# Catan - Discarding fish to draw more from the supply

Tags: catan, catan-traders-and-barbarians

In *The Fishermen of Catan*, if a player has 7 fish tokens and a roll would have them receive more, can they discard the ones they don't want to draw the new ones?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

---

In the original scenario named [*The Fishermen of Catan*](https://www.catan.com/game/fishermen-catan), there was no limit to how many fish tokens could be kept. A revised version was published in [*Traders & Barbarians*](https://www.catan.com/game/catan-traders-barbarians-expansion). This version included the following rule:

> **7 fish tokens at most**: You are not allowed to have more than 7 fish tokens at any one time. If you already have 7 fish tokens and would obtain another 1 or 2 fish tokens for a settlement or city, you may exchange one of your fish tokens with a fish token from the supply (hoping for a token with more fish on it).

So if you couldn't draw a fish tile because you already have 7, you may first discard one of your fish tokens.

However, it's not clear exactly when and how often this can be done.

- What if you have 6 fish tokens and would obtain 2 from a city?
- What if you have 6 fish tokens and would obtain 1 each of two settlements?
- What if you have 7 fish tokens and would obtain 2 from a city?
- What if you have 7 fish tokens and would obtain 1 each of two settlements?
- What if you have 7 fish tokens and would obtain 1 from a settlement and 2 from a city?